How to introduce a newline inside a color text?
I have this phrase in Markdown:
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{En el análisis descriptivo se observa que la desviación estándar de la variable "Millones_Pesos" es muy grande lo que indica que la dispersión de los datos es notable. Además, al observar los valores mínimo y máximo se puede observar que el rango de valores es muy grande. Además, el promedio está alejado del valor máximo lo que indica un corrimiento a la izquierda de la distribución.}}$

How can introduce a newline inside that colored line?
I have tried the following, but none worked:

\
\\
\s\s
\n
/


Use \newline for creating a new line. OR try using \text functions in separate lines.
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{En el análisis descriptivo se observa que la desviación estándar de la variable "Millones_Pesos" es muy grande, lo que indica que la dispersión de los datos es notable.}}$
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{Además, al observar los valores mínimo y máximo, se puede observar que el rango de valores es muy grande.}}$
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{Además, el promedio está alejado del valor máximo, lo que indica un corrimiento a la izquierda de la distribución.}}$


It did not work in my case

$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{En el análisis descriptivo se observa que la desviación estándar de la variable "Millones_Pesos" es muy grande, lo que indica que la dispersión de los datos es notable.}}$
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{Además, al observar los valores mínimo y máximo, se puede observar que el rango de valores es muy grande.}}$
$\color{LimeGreen}{\text{Además, el promedio está alejado del valor máximo, lo que indica un corrimiento a la izquierda de la distribución.}}$
try separate text sections

Yes, it works like that. But, a code should exist to be more practical. Thank you anyway

Edited the answer
